# javascript - for loop appendChild real time display

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, appendchild

I want to setup the for-loop  to print out msg one by one,  I just delayed the console.log msg, and appendChild msg will displayed with the for-loop is end. how can I fix it.

following is code
http://jsfiddle.net/wts8gb8g/

```
function createLogDiv(){
    if(document.getElementById("log") == null){
        var log = document.createElement("div");
        log.id = "log";
        document.body.appendChild(log);
        var css = document.createElement("style");
        css.type = "text/css";
        css.innerHTML = "#log {width: 400px;height: 200px;background: black;position: absolute;top: 0;opacity: 0.75;color: lime;overflow: auto;text-align: left;margin-top: 46px;}";
        document.body.appendChild(css);
    }
}

function log(str){
    var xx = document.createElement("div");
    xx.innerHTML=str+"</br>";
    document.getElementById("log").appendChild(xx);
    console.log(str);
}

function sleep(milliseconds){
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++){
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}


createLogDiv();
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    log(i);
    sleep(500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your loop to this:

```
createLogDiv();
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    setTimeout(function(x){log(x)},500*i,i);
}
```